# Django Ldap Connection Setup

Tags: python, django, ldap, ldapconnection

I am trying to setup a LDAP connection in Django. Does anyone have any sample code? I need to know what information I need to place inside of the `settings.py`.

I keep getting the following error message:

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH must be an LDAPSearch instance.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a specific backend? 
Assuming you are using [`django-auth-ldap`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap/) the docs are [quite detailed](http://packages.python.org/django-auth-ldap/#example-configuration).

Comment: Yes. I am using backend. However, I can not import ldap from within my project on eclipse. But when I run python from cmd I can import ldap.